# iPhone/iPad app delopment and BundleId

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad

Okay so here is my situation.  About a year ago I released my very first iPhone app!  (Yeah).  Since then I have been working on making it into a universal app.  In doing this, I actually went  ahead and created a brand new universal app and then proceeded to code accordingly.

So now I want to release this app but since the app was created brand new, it has a different bundle Id.  I don't want to alienate the users that bought the previous version for just the iPhone so is it as simple as just changing the universal app bundle Id to the one I used for the iPhone and publish that way?  Will this fly with apples publishing system?

Thanks in advance for any and all help.

Geo...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be absolutely fine. The devices will just replace the app with the new version - as long as your new one uses the same data storage / preferences etc there's no reason why that won't work.

NB This answer assumes that you are going to release it as an upgrade to your previous app.

Comment: Yes.  To be honest, I assumed that if I use the same Bundle Id it would know it is an upgrade?  (Plus the fact that when it is submitted to apple it is listed as an upgrade)  What do you mean by data storage preferences?

Comment: As in make sure your new app uses the same keys/values in NSUserDefaults etc - you're almost certainly doing this already though!